# Forcing object to deallocate/go out of scope to call destructor

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I know it's bad practice to manually deallocate, so I don't want to do that. Is there a good way to make a class deallocate itself? I wrote a program that makes a template matrix, and overloaded the copy contructor. I want to now implement the move contructor/operator using copy and then deallocating the matrix that's given in the parameter.

```
template <typename T>
class matrix
{
    private:
        int cols;
        int rows;
        T **array_;      //pointer to array of pointers
    public:
        ~matrix();

        matrix <T> & operator=(const matrix <T> & matr){
            CopyMatrix(matr);        //copy, not move
            return *this;            //matr still exists
        }

        matrix<T>(matrix<T> && matr){     //move contructor
            CopyMatrix(matr);
            delete matr.array_;        //will this work?
        }

        matrix <T> & operator=(matrix<T> && matr){  //move operator
            CopyMatrix(matr);
            delete matr.array_;        //will this work?
            return *this;
        }
}


template <typename T>
matrix <T>::~matrix(){
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        delete [] array_[i];
    }
    delete array_;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of managing the array memory yourself.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I have to use arrays here. I know it's bad practice, but I'm not allowed to use vector

Comment: Correction to the destructor: `delete[] array_;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the "move" semantics, move the relevant data from the object being moved from to the object being constructed.

```
 matrix<T>(matrix<T> && matr) : cols(matr.cols),
                                rows(matr.rows),
                                array_(matr.array_) // Move the ownership of the data to the new object.
{
    matr.array_ = nullptr;  // matr does not own the data any longer.
}
```

and then, make sure that the destructor deals with it correctly.

```
template <typename T>
matrix <T>::~matrix(){
   if ( array_ != nullptr )
   {    
      for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
          delete [] array_[i];
      }
      delete array_;
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I feel really dumb, I'm still new at this. Thanks a lot

Comment: @YesImhere, don't feel bad. We all go through those stages while learning new stuff.